# select control loses all options after ng-select

Tags: json, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a select box like this...

```
<select class="form-control m-b"
    ng-options="portfolios.id as portfolios.product_name for portfolios in portfolio"
    data-ng-model="portfolio" ng-change="getPriceAttributes()">
</select>
```

When a user selects an option from the select box, the function `getPriceAttributes()` is called...

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('QuoteApp');

var quoteBuilderController = function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.formData = {};   

// this populates the select
    $http.get('scripts/json/sample-products.json')
        .then(function(res){
           $scope.portfolio = res.data.Connectivity;
        });

//this is called when a user selects an option from the select control
    $scope.getPriceAttributes = function() {
        $http.get('scripts/json/sample-product-attribute-response.json')
            .then(function(res){
                $scope.formFields = res.data;
            });
    };
};

app.controller('quoteBuilderController', ['$scope', '$http', quoteBuilderController]);

}());
```

When I load the page, the select box has a list of options which come from a json file. When I select an option from the select box, `getPriceattributes()` is called, but the options in the select box disappear, leaving an empty select control. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thank you

Comment: From what I see this behaviour cannot be justified. The problem could be in another place in the code, e.g. what happens with the `formFields`? Can you reproduce it in a fiddle (you can use timeouts to emulate the services)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I will put a fiddle together

Comment: I don't think your ng-model and your ng-options should use the same naming (portfolio), that is likely causing a conflict along the way. Change ng-model to another variable name and see if it works.

Comment: Also, do a console.log(res.data); inside your .then() function to see what is sent back.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info here is an angular template to get you started, just fork it and you're good to go.